# Why NSData convert to NSString crashed on ios10

Tags: objective-c, ios10

Recently my app got some crash report when convent NSData to NSString on ios10, the attachment image is the crash stack.The crash is collected by fabric and I can't reproduce it. 
Does any one else met the same problem, Please tell me how to avoid the problem?

I have already checked the nsdata and ensure it is not nil.

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18b7f3014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18b8bb450 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18b767400 abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18b837a5c _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 330
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18b839028 nano_realloc + 648
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18b82b240 malloc_zone_realloc + 180
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18c7e3958 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 692
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18c76d81c CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation + 104
8  Foundation                     0x18d253f64 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithData:encoding:] + 148
```

[here is the crash detail screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOPm6.png)

Comment: Probably because NSData is NULL

Comment: Check if NSData is nil?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: But i didn't understand that how you set `NSData` to `NULL` can you paste code? & if not then why you need to add check `[data isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]` .... is that that correct way to init `NSData` to NULL instead of `nil` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your data is not nil and not Null

```
if (data && ![data isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
}
```

Comment: I only check not nil.I will add check not NULL in next version and will keep follow the problem.thanks

Comment: if data is NULL, it will crash with different crash stack, so it should not the reason

Answer (score 0):

Check condition for `NSData` is not nil, `data.length > 0` means it contains some value.

```
if(data.length > 0){
   NSString *tempString =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  //Do your tasks here
}
```